# Updated my Typescript definitions, broke angular directive

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-directive

I just updated my Typescript definitions to the latest available today.  In `angular.d.ts`, this is now the definition of `scope` from the `IDirective` interface:

```
interface IDirective {
    ...
    scope?: boolean | {[boundProperty: string]: string};
    ...
}
```

My directive is defined as such (with letters in place of the actual names and irrelevant code omitted):

```
export class MyDirective implements angular.IDirective {
    scope = {
        a: "&",
        b: "@?",
        c: "=?",
        d: "=?",
        e: "@?",
    }
}
```

I'm getting this compile-time error:

> Error Class 'MyDirective' incorrectly implements interface 'IDirective'.
>     Types of property 'scope' are incompatible.
>
> Type '{ a: string; b: string; c: string; d: string; e: string; }' is not assignable to type 'boolean | { [boundProperty: string]: string; }'.
>
> Type '{ a: string; b: string; c: string; d: string; e: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ [boundProperty: string]: string; }'.
>
> Index signature is missing in type '{ a: string; b: string; c: string; d: string; e: string; }'.

I don't understand why I'm getting this.  Each of the properties is a string, which is what the `{ [boundProperty: string]: string; }` part wants, isn't it?

How do I change my scope definition to fit with the updated definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and it transpiles fine.  I would close and restart whatever IDE you're using and see if this error goes away; that seems to work quite frequently for me as a Visual Studio user when TypeScript errors don't make sense.

If that doesn't work, make sure you have your version of the TypeScript compiler updated to the most recent version.

I know it's not the latest but this is the typing I'm using: registry:dt/angular#1.5.0+20161101124950
And my version of TypeScript: 2.1.5.0

Comment: What TS version are you compiling with?  It just occurred to me that I might need to upgrade my TS compiler as well.

Comment: If you update your answer to "You need to upgrade your TypeScript compiler", I'll mark it as the accepted answer.  That's what it was.